# in app purchase question:unable to get product information

Tags: iphone

I have created an in app purchase in itunes connect,
since I have not tested my new in app-purchase application,I associated it with my free app.I have finished it with the developer guide,and now its status is pending developer approval.

However,during my test in the new application:

//the featureAId is the same as the created in app purchase id in itunes connect

SKProductsRequest* request=[[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObjects:featureAId,nil]];
request.delegate = self;
[request start];

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
  {
  NSLog(@"did receiveResponse!");
  NSLog(@"%d",[response.invalidProductIdentifiers count]);
  }

//the logging is 1,showing that we the product information can not be retrived.
I have tested the application in device,and it is connected to the internet through wifi.

what is the problem? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Is the AppID for the application you are running different than the AppID of the app containing the in-app purchase?  This would probably cause a problem, and unless I'm reading your question wrong, that sounds like it's the case.

So, if your app is "com.company.myFirstApp" and you are trying to buy an in-app purchase from "com.company.mySecondApp" called "com.company.mySecondApp.inAppPurchase1," it will fail.

Add the in-app purchase for the same app in iTunes Connect.  Fill out all the required information with the exception of uploading the binary and you can test out in-app purchases to your heart's content afterwards on the device.